# Any way in Chrome Developer tools to trace what changes the value in an object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working in JavaScript and something is mysteriously changing the value inside of one of my objects.

It is most certainly nothing that I've coded myself - it's very likely a 3rd party package, and a very very complicated one at that.

Is there some way to have Chrome Developer keep track of the value of something inside of an object and, once it changes, alert the user as to what function in the code caused it to change?

Comment: would `Object.observe` -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe help?

Comment: The JavaScript debugger has advanced a lot in the dev tools. I would suggest giving them a whirl and putting a breakpoint where the object may be changing -- there should be a panel that shows you the state of every variable and object that has been declared.

Comment: @JaromandaX, `Object.observe` doesn't seem to allow you to see *what* made the change to the object. It shows you that it changed, what it changed to, what it was before, but no indication of what did the changing.

Comment: @aug I've been setting breakpoints but I need something to just tell me which line of code caused the change in value. I have an event handler that literally does nothing. It's just a blank function. But once the listener hears the event go off, one of the values in my variables changes. Setting a breakpoint in the event handler itself simply shows me that the data has changed, not what started the change.